# How to use arrays in a leap year finder

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that can take input of multiple leap years ina row through an array and then output whether they are leap years or not on their own separate lines. I can't seem to figure out the problem. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYear2 {

    static boolean[] leapYearStatus = new boolean[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter consecutive years above 1582 with");
        System.out.println("spaces separating them then press enter.");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.nextLine()+ " ";
        String[] inputString = new String[input.length()/5];
        int[] inputValues = new int[input.length()/5];
        inputString = input.split("\\s+");

        for (int i =0; i < input.length()/5;i++)
            inputValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputString[i]);

        LeapYear2 check = new LeapYear2();

        check.checkLeap(inputValues);
        check.output(leapYearStatus, inputValues);
        scan.close();
    }

    public void checkLeap(int value[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] % 4 == 0)
                if (value[i] % 400 == 0)
                    leapYearStatus[i] = true;
                else if (value[i] % 100 == 0)
                    leapYearStatus[i] = false;

        }
    }

    public void output(boolean[] leapYearStatus, int value[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++)
            if(leapYearStatus[i] && value[i] > 1582){
                System.out.println(value[i] + " is a leap year!");
            }else if(!leapYearStatus[i] && value[i] > 1582 ){
                System.out.println(value[i] + " is not a leap year.");
            }else {
                System.out.println(value[i] + " is too small! (<= 1582)");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Let's start one step before that.  What are you putting into the program?  What is your expected output?  Why is it different than what you're expecting?

Comment: I am trying to put into the program a string of years separated by spaces. For example: "2003 3049 1253 5432 3241". Then have an output such that it takes each year and tells whether the year is larger enough and whether it is a leap year or not. Example: "2012 is not a leap year.".

Comment: Okay.  So why do you think it's broken?

Comment: It sets all the years to false. This only changes if I put one year in only, and if the year is too small.

Comment: `leapYearStatus[i] = true` is that a typo, you are missing `;`

Comment: Ok. I changed the code. I get this output when I put in my example numbers. 2003 is not a leap year.
3049 is not a leap year.
1253 is too small! (<= 1582)
5432 is not a leap year.
3241 is not a leap year.
This is clearly incorrect as 5432 IS a leap year.

Comment: You need to check `if (value[i] % 400 == 0)` within the `if (value[i] % 100 == 0)`, not in the `else if`.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, but the code still runs the same with the semicolon. I also updated my code for you guys to see.

Comment: After your edit, all you might need is `else {leapYearStatus[i] = true;}`, after the century-checks.

Comment: Not sure how important this is for what you're doing, but not every country handled leap years the same way historically. For example, Sweden had a Feb 30th once, in 1712, and was not having leap years at all for about 40 years. Ref: http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/trivia.html

Comment: That worked! Thank you! If you don't mind re-posting that as an answer I'll accept it as one for you. @MickMnemonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of nested `if`, you can reduce to one `if`. Its the same but more readable

```
if (value[i] % 400 == 0 || (value[i] % 4 == 0 && value[i] % 100 != 0) ) {
    leapYearStatus[i] = true;
} else {
    leapYearStatus[i] = false;
}
```